# Core Animation + Core Audio + sleep not happening in the order expected

Tags: objective-c, audio, asynchronous, core-animation

Below is some code I'm working with.

What I want/expect:

- Image fades in; sound plays; delay; image fades out.

What happens

- Delay, sound plays, image fades in and then fades out immediately after

Any help much appreciated.

**ViewController.m**

```
[self fadein];
NSString *tempFN;
SystemSoundID soundID;
tempFN = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@.caf", 
          [myGlobals.gTitleArray objectAtIndex:myGlobals.gQuoteCountForLoop]];
NSString *soundFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], tempFN];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
                         sizeof (sessionCategory),
                         &sessionCategory); 
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)soundFileURL, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

// Now fade-out the image after a few seconds delay
sleep(3);
[self fadeout];

-(IBAction)fadein
{
    [UIImageView beginAnimations:NULL context:nil];
    [UIImageView setAnimationDuration:2];
    [faceImage setAlpha:0.3];
    [UIImageView commitAnimations];
}

-(IBAction)fadeout
{
    [UIImageView beginAnimations:NULL context:nil];
    [UIImageView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [faceImage setAlpha:0];
    [UIImageView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is when you use "sleep(5)". Using the sleep() function blocks the main thread so nothing can be done for that time period. It is exceedingly rare to use the sleep() function in Objective-C except maybe in some command-line utilities.
I recommend that you use an NSTimer instead of the sleep() function.

Hope this helps.

//Edit
Also if you really must use sleep(), you should instead use the sleepForTimeInterval: function of the NSThread class and get the rest of your code running on a secondary thread. Once again, I really don't think you should use the sleep() function or any related functions.

Answer (score 0):

As the other poster said, sleep is the problem. Sleep freezes the main thread. Forget that sleep exists. Never use it. The only time sleep is EVER valid is on a secondary thread, when you want that thread to stop running for a period, and then only if you really really know what you are doing with concurrency (a very advanced topic)

What you should do is rewrite your animation code to use animateWithDuration:animations:completion:

Provide a completion block that invokes the next animation using a nested call to animateWithDuration:animations:completion:

Each animation will run to the end, and then invoke the next one.

BTW, you should look at AVAudioPlayer. It is more powerful than AudioServices, and easier to use. You just create an AVAudioPlayer and tell it to play.

If you want a step in your animation to wait for a sound to compete, AVAudioPlayer takes a delegate that it will call once the sound is done playing.

**Here's how I would suggest reworking your animation sequence:**

Before you begin your animation sequence, set up an AVAudioPlayer and make your view controller it's delegate.

Write an animateWithDuration:animations:completion call where the animations block does your fade in.

In the completion block, start an AVAudioPlayer playing.

In the AVAudioPlayer delegate method audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:, invoke another animateWithDuration:animations:completion: method to fade your view out again.